# shell command to find values in column appearing more than "twice"

Tags: shell

I have data that looks like this (I've put a "d" on the end of indices that are expected to be removed), but original file won't necessarily be sorted:
PPBondedFieldOver2NeedsFixing.csv:

```
ABR: 1-1-1-41,2298961,578766
ABRd: 1-1-1-42,9109441,1581024
ABRd: 1-1-1-45,9109441,1581024
ABRd: 1-1-1-46,9109441,1581024
ABRd: 1-1-1-43,9109442,10612609
ABRd: 1-1-1-43,9109442,10612609
ABRd: 1-1-1-44,9109442,10612609
ABRd: 1-1-1-45,9109443,14210513
ABRd: 1-1-1-46,9109443,14210513
ABRd: 1-1-1-47,9109443,14210513
ABR: 1-1-1-45,9109444,14210513
ABR: 1-1-1-46,9109444,14210513
ABR: 1-1-2-23,9109445,1761077
ABR: 1-1-2-24,9109445,1761077
```

I'm trying to find a shell command that I can use to remove the ones where the part between the commas has a count over 2.  Later I will have a similar file where I remove the ones with a count over 1.

I'm trying this to get the list of ones over 2, but it's giving me a long blank output:

```
cut -d "," -f 2 PPBondedFieldOver2NeedsFixing.csv | sort | uniq | gawk '$1>2{print $2}'
```

For that one, I was trying to follow [list of ip's occurring more than 3 times](https://superuser.com/questions/563804/output-the-items-that-showed-up-2-times-and-more), but that is different, because they only have one column.

I want my output to look like this eventually:

```
ABR: 1-1-1-41,2298961,578766
ABR: 1-1-1-45,9109444,14210513
ABR: 1-1-1-46,9109444,14210513
ABR: 1-1-2-23,9109445,1761077
ABR: 1-1-2-24,9109445,1761077
```

My list of ones appearing over 3 times will look like this:

```
9109441
9109442
9109443
```

Comment: It's unclear why `1-1-1-42` was removed but `1-1-1-41` was kept?

Comment: Because 2298961 doesn't have 2 like it.

Comment: 9109441, 9109442 and 9109443 have 3 in the list so they need to be removed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is how I got it to work to get the list of ones appearing more than twice:

```
cut -d "," -f 2 PPBondedFieldOver2NeedsFixing.csv | sort | awk '++A[$1]>2'
```

This will return

```
9109441
9109442
9109443
```

Comment: I wound up using this.

Answer (score 1):

This can done using a single `awk` without any need to call multiple expensive commands like `sort`:

```
awk -F, 'FNR == NR { counts[$2]++; next }
counts[$2] > 2 && !seen[$2]++{print $2 > "tmpFile"}
counts[$2] <= 2' PPBondedFieldOver2NeedsFixing.csv{,}
```

```
ABR: 1-1-1-41,2298961,578766
ABR: 1-1-1-45,9109444,14210513
ABR: 1-1-1-46,9109444,14210513
ABR: 1-1-2-23,9109445,1761077
ABR: 1-1-2-24,9109445,1761077

cat tmpFile

9109441
9109442
9109443
```

Comment: I'm trying to figure out what that has for file.  So the first file is the original file (PPBondedFieldOver2NeedsFixing.csv), and is the second file the output file with the list of ones over 2?

Comment: `awk -F, 'FNR == NR{counts[$2]++; next} counts[$2] <= 2' PPBondedFieldOver2NeedsFixing.csv PPBondedFieldOver2NeedsFixing.csv` or shorter `awk -F, 'FNR == NR{counts[$2]++; next} counts[$2] <= 2' PPBondedFieldOver2NeedsFixing.csv{,}`

Comment: I need an intermediate file with the ones for removal, ie. showing 9109441, 9109442, 9109443.